# An Analog of List.h in .Net

Tags: .net, c++, list, collections

I used to use List.h to work with lists in C++, but are there any similar libraries in .Net ? Becouse I can't use List.h for managed types.

Comment: What is List.h? In C++ you should use std::list to work with lists

Comment: You would probably like to study more about Linq-to-objects and the System.Linq namespace

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [System.Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.aspx) and [System.Collections.Generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.aspx) namespaces.
There, you'll find classes like [`ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx), [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(VS.80).aspx), etc...

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of using List:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
myList.Add("Item1");
myList.Add("Item2");
myList.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s.ToString()));
```

and here is an example of LinkedList:

```
LinkedList<int> myList = new LinkedList<int>();

myList.AddFirst(14);             
myList.AddLast(20);                            
myList.AddLast(34);             
myList.AddBefore(myList.Last, 65); 

LinkedListNode<int> myNode = myList.First;
while (myNode != null)
{
  Console.WriteLine(myNode.Value);
  myNode = myNode.Next;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) achieves the same funcionality.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the STL list then you'll want the the [LinkedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) generic class found in [System.Collections.Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx)

The .Net [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx) generic class is more like an STL vector